# Friends Keyboard opens up programs instead of typing

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

My friend bought a keyboard that has been working well for about a month. All of a sudden, his keyboard will start opening system settings and programs instead of typing.

Previously Alt-Windows key would revert the keyboard to a keyboard, but this too has stopped working.

Are there any Windows settings that could be causing the problem?

Comment: You can try following possible solutions: 1. run troubleshooter (settings>Update & Security>Troubleshoot>Additional troubleshooters>Keyboard) 2. Uninstall and reinstall the keyboard in Device Manager 3. makre sure Use Sticky Keys is off (Settings>Ease of Access>Keyboard) 4. See if the onscreen keyboard works properly. If it works well, I am guessing a key on the hard keyboard is stuck down or it has some other fault.

Comment: These are all good solutions. As of yet the problem only occurs when he plays GTA5 so I'm guessing he's pressing keys that start the problem. If you answer the question I'll give you a correct answer